# Indexing files of all format

Tags: java, lucene

```
private static class TextFilesFilter implements FileFilter {
 public boolean accept(File path) {
   return path.getName().toLowerCase()        
         .endsWith("*.txt");                  
 }
```

The above snippet finds file that ends with .txt extension. I need to find all files. I changed the line ".*" but it is not finding anything. How to find all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the whole filter.  Or simply return true.